# Current state of LESS CSS on Linux

Tags: less

What should I use if I want to use less.js locally and have a file automatically recompiled if either this file or an imported file has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) is a LESS compiler written entirely in PHP, making it very easy to run on the server side if you're already using PHP. It was finally just added to [Packagist](http://packagist.org/app.php/packages/leafo/lessphp) yesterday!  You can install it on a project to project basis using [composer](http://getcomposer.org/).  Here is an example composer.json file for declaring it as a dependency to your own project:

```
{
    "require": {
        "leafo/lessphp": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best approach given that this is for a WordPress project. Although I plan to use plessc initially, it is useful to have the option to integrate the LESS compiler with the project and invoke it if the configuration is changed.

Comment: I’m new to Stack Overflow (I just began to actively answer questions), but I think there's several wrong things with this question.

First : the title is misleading. You should rephrase it for something more descriptive. Something like : Automatically recompiling a modified file with less on Linux.
Second : the approved answer is specific to PHP. It may answer your current needs, but it does not really answer the question you asked, in which no particular technology was specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dotless with mono.. if you have mono then run dotless with the -w (watch) option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use watchdog and [this script](http://keyes.ie/automatically-compile-less-files/), which I found useful.
To install watchdog, you’ll first need to have the python setup tools installed (`apt-get install python-setuptools` assuming you’re using Debian or a Debian-based distribution such as Ubuntu).
Then, simply `easy_install watchdog`. You'll be able to run the lesswatch script once the installation is complete.